# can I query context from within seed method of context initializer

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am initializing my database from a bunch of sql scripts. Then I would like to query the data when adding more data so foreign key relations match up. Yet in my example, the "painting" variable always ends up null even though the data is there. Is is possible to query the data inside this seed method? Do I have to commit the data or something?

```
class ArtConvergenceInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ArtConvergence>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ArtConvergence context)
        {            

            var seedfilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToInitializationScript"].ToString();
            foreach(var file in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(seedfilePath,"*.sql"))
            {
                var sqlCommand = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var painting = context.Mediums.Where(x => x.MediumType == "Painting" && x.SpecificMedium == null).FirstOrDefault();
            var oilOnCanvas = context.Mediums.Where(x => x.MediumType == "Painting" && x.SpecificMedium == "oil on canvas").FirstOrDefault();              

        }
```

Comment: I know you can ,because I am doing it as well. I don't think you need to call SaveChanges after the ExecuteSqlcommand. without looking at your script, I am not sure why this would not give you back data. The script is finishing and inserting?

Answer (score 0):

Once you use direct SQL scripts it should not be too hard to write SQL script which will correctly insert data with existing foreign keys. I did it many times. Keep your initialization logic together.